# how to merge cells in fastreport 4?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

sample data

01 A AA
01 A BB
02 B CC
03 A DD
03 A EE

the primary key is first column.
the first column and second column are common value.
the last column is personal value.
i want to merge rows in the first column and second column when the value of the first column is change.

my way is
first, write in fastreport's code using 'if' command.
second, use 'groupheader' and add the common columns in the section.

however, the first way have a problem that i don't know how to control index.
the second way is the groupheader's columns overflow PageFooter when a group end at the end of a page and the other group start at the first of next page.

please..... answer me...TTTTTT!

[the first box is Groupheader's columns and the second box is overflowed data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4cvG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TfrxDBCrossView object